# Name the object the value of a string?

Tags: java, class, object, dynamic, properties

I have been given data that is water stream quality in Ontario.  Any time station is mentioned I am refering to a place at which data was taken.  Any time result is mentioned I am refering to the data that had been collected.

I have an array with the following:

```
String[] stationArray = {1049, 05/12/2004, 13:50}; //{station id, date, time}
```

I would like to make this into an object. If I knew what the station id would be all the time, I would do this (assuming I have a station class):

```
String date = "05/12/2004;
String time = "13:50";
Station 1049 = new Station(date, time);
```

But I don't know what the station id will be as I have 2000+ stations (and 100 000+ results) and I don't want to hard code the numbers into the program.  So how can I do something that accomplishes this:

```
String date = "05/12/2004";
String time = "13:50";
String station_id = stationArray[0]; //this way I can pop each array into a function to create the Station object for me
Station station_id = new Station(date, time);
```

If I was able to do this, I would send the array to a function and create the objects that way because I could change the `station_id` variable for each object.  The reason I want to do this is because I have another class `Result` which has several properties including the station id the data was gathered at (which is of type `Station`).  This may not be the best way to use the data but I must show a `has-a` relationship and this is the only opportunity I can find to use it.

At the end of it all, I was hoping I could use something like...

```
result.station_id.location //where station_id is of type Station
```

...to find where a set of data was taken.  If station_id is a `String`, I would have to take it and compare it to an array of `Station`'s then find the location that way.

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer, Station>`?

Comment: The hashmap approach from the duplicate is what you want here

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was thinking about that but then I would not be able to have a property of type `Station` for my Result objects. (i.e. result.station_id)

Comment: Your code snippets are very confusing. In one you use invalid variable name, in another you overwrite `station_id` value immediately after you assigned it.  Do you understand how constructors work?

Comment: @PM77 the OP is using imaginary syntax to try to explain the concept of dynamic variable names. It's not supposed to compile

Comment: @user You can use the map and also have the station ID as a field within the object; it isnt either-or

Comment: @RichardTingle well that is what I originally wanted to do but then the field would be a `String`.  I want to be able to have a property in `Result` objects that is of type `Station`

Comment: Ok, but surely you could have that, and then if you want the ID it would be result.getStation().getStationID();